# Fade out corners of div -- over different backgrounds

Tags: html, css, gradient, fade

I've got this working using a static black background on my games splash screen:

[[image: 1]]

If too small: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BttUw.png

As you can see it works on a black background, but when we are on any other background, we simply see black instead of the actual background.

This makes sense, because I'm using a gradient like:

```
#waves::before {
    left:0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%);
}

#waves::after {
    right:0;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%);

}
```

Soo... technically it's working as intended. I just can't figure out how to do it like I want it to work.

My goal: fade out the div so that the waveform corners appear to fade out.

How i attempted it: `waves` is a div, so I leveraged `before` and `after` psuedo-elements, and gave it a width LARGER than required (so there is some overlap), and then used a gradient to fade.

If anyone knows how to do this, that would be great!

I did search, which is where I got the idea of a gradient from. I couldn't find anything that would suit this use case (multiple backgrounds)

To clarify, this is my goal:

[image: 2]]

Comment: Can't you use an SVG or something? This seems to be something vectors would be good for

Comment: A mask is what you seem to be needing but the problem is - (a) Pure CSS Masks have very poor browser support and work only in WebKit powered browsers and (b) SVG Masks, I think, work in IE only when applied on an SVG `<image>` element. You cannot use it to mask a normal HTML element which has a background image. So, I think you'd have to go with the latter (SVG approach) but I don't know if that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your image is mostly black, You can use a mix mode to overlay it over the background.

And keep the way you mask it with black on the sides

```css
.bkg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200);
  background-size: cover;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent), linear-gradient(to left, black, transparent), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhk0G.png);
  background-size: 20% 100%, 20% 100%, cover;
  background-position: left center, right center, center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div class="bkg"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```